# Can we impliment the operator over loading in Web services?

Tags: c#, asp.net

is it possible to implement operator over loading in Web services in .net

Mehar

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i wan to use operatior over loading concept in web services

Comment: I think Mehar means method overloading not operator overloading.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you want to do?

Comment: @Joe - he is very specifically asking about operator overloading.

Comment: we are using operator overloading in c# example 
public static Complex operator +(Complex c1, Complex c2) 
   {
      return new Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary);
   }
can we do in web service by using Mathematical operators

Answer (score 1):

Operator overloading is used to overload the use of different operators on an object.

You can do this in the objects used within a webservice, but if you want the webservice itself to be overloaded this way, it cannot be done.

There is no way to expose operator overloads over a webservice (some languages that may consume the webservice may not support operator overloading).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this article](http://scottwhite.blogspot.com/2005/09/overloading-web-service-methods-in-net.html) which shows you how to overload.

You have you're overloaded methods and then use the `[WebMethod(MessageName="MethodName")]` attribute to specify the name of the method in the web service.

Comment: can u plese send me another link. the existing one is not open

Comment: This is not operator overloading, this is method overloading.